# Load javascript in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to javascript dev in general and webpack in particular. I want to use this chess board module (https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/) in my project. It sees to be exporting ChessBoard object. My project is using ES6, so I would love to be able to

`import { ChessBoard } from 'chessboard'`

or

`import ChessBoard from 'chessboard'`

I understand that I need some sort of loader for this. I have tried to add expose loader in the same way I use it for jQuery

```
{test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery"},
{test: require.resolve("chessboard"), loader: "expose?ChessBoard!./vendor/chessboard/js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"}
```

But I get "Error: Cannot find module 'chessboard'" error. Same if I replace ChessBoard with $. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Is expose even the right loader for what I am trying to do?

Here is my webpack config for reference (without the broken chessboard expose test)

```js
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/main.js')],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery"},
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude:  /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel', query: {presets: ['react', 'es2015']} }, 
      /* CSS loaders */
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css'},
      {test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less'},
      /* font loaders for bootstrap */
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Test',
      inject: false,
      template: 'node_modules/html-webpack-template/index.ejs',
      appMountId: 'app',
      devServer: 'http://localhost:8080',
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that the chessboard.js is just a anonymous function and not a AMD or CommonJS module, and  you may have to look at adding shims using webpack.

> Not all JS files can be used directly with webpack. The file might be
>   in an unsupported module format, or not even in any module format.
>   https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire webpack.config.js file it's tricky to say what the issue is. Basically you need to tell webpack to include `/node_modules/' into the list of paths it looks in for js modules.

You will need to add something like this to the `resolve` section of `webpack.config.js`.

```
 modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
```

Comment: I already have NPM packages loading just fine. The module I am trying to load is distributed as source, not as a package. I will post my entire webpack config.

Comment: Have you tried including the path in your `import` statement?

Comment: Basically you need to tell webpack to add the path to wherever the code you want to import is. So it knows where to look.

Comment: I know. How do I do that?

Comment: When you `import ChessBoard from 'chessboard'`, it must be located under `node_modules` or inside one of the folders you have specified at `resolve.root` in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Well node_modules is for NPM packages, I don't want to put software in there that NPM is not aware of. I will try with resolve.root. I was under impression that I could use a loader of some sort to specify where to look for it.

Comment: Mind you that I get "Cannot find module" when I run webpack, not when I access my pages.

Comment: When loading packages that aren't node modules you need to specify them like `import './myFile.js'`or `import Something from './myFile.js'`or `import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent'`. You can't use just its name as it will always resolve to node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need something like this in your webpack.config.js:

```
...
       resolve: {
            modules: [
                'node_modules',
                path.join( __dirname, 'node_modules' ),
                path.resolve( './src' ),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to do two things:**

1.) under plugins add:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   "window['jQuery']": "jquery"
})
```

2.) Install the `script-loader` plugin and import the script like this:

```
import 'script-loader!./chessboard.js';
```